# How to perform functions over groupby results in pandas in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have used this code to compute values for the different quality metrics of each user in each cluster

```
>>> for name, group in df.groupby(["Cluster_id", "User"]):
...     print 'group name:', name
...     print 'group rows:'
...     print group
...     print 'counts of Quality values:'
...     print group["Quality"].value_counts()
...     raw_input()
...
```

But now I get the output as

```
group rows:
                tag                       user                    quality  cluster
676    black fabric  http://steve.nl/user_1002          usefulness-useful        1
708      blond wood  http://steve.nl/user_1002          usefulness-useful        1
709      blond wood  http://steve.nl/user_1002    problematic-misspelling        1
1410         eames?  http://steve.nl/user_1002      usefulness-not_useful        1
1411         eames?  http://steve.nl/user_1002  problematic-misperception        1
3649  rocking chair  http://steve.nl/user_1002          usefulness-useful        1
3650  rocking chair  http://steve.nl/user_1002  problematic-misperception        1
counts of Quality Values:
usefulness-useful            3
problematic-misperception    2
usefulness-not_useful        1
problematic-misspelling      1
```

What I would like to do now is to have a check condition i.e:

```
if quality==usefulness-useful:
 good = good + 1
else:
 bad = bad + 1
```

I tried writing the output:

```
counts of Quality Values:
usefulness-useful            3
problematic-misperception    2
usefulness-not_useful        1
problematic-misspelling      1
```

into a variable and tried traversing the variable row by row, but it does not work. Can someone give me suggestions, on how to do computations on certain rows.

Comment: Can you add the output of `df.head().to_dict()` to your question so others can troubleshoot using your data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've got a group, you can iterate row by row using the `.iterrows()` method.  It gives you a row index and the row itself:

```
In [33]: for row_number, row in group.iterrows():
   ....:     print row_number
   ....:     print row
   ....:     
676
Tag                        black fabric
User          http://steve.nl/user_1002
Quality               usefulness-useful
Cluster_id                            1
Name: 676
708
Tag                          blond wood
User          http://steve.nl/user_1002
Quality               usefulness-useful
Cluster_id                            1
Name: 708
[etc]
```

and each of these rows can be indexed into like a dictionary, for example:

```
In [48]: row
Out[48]: 
Tag                       rocking chair
User          http://steve.nl/user_1002
Quality       problematic-misperception
Cluster_id                            1
Name: 3650

In [49]: row["User"]
Out[49]: 'http://steve.nl/user_1002'

In [50]: row["Tag"]
Out[50]: 'rocking chair'
```

And so you can write your loop like

```
good = 0
bad = 0
for row_number, row in group.iterrows():
    if row['Quality'] == 'usefulness-useful':
        good += 1
    else:
        bad += 1
print 'good', good, 'bad', bad
```

which gives

```
good 3 bad 4
```

That's a perfectly fine way to do it if it makes sense to you.  Another way is to work directly from the counts in the `Quality` column:

```
In [54]: counts = group["Quality"].value_counts()

In [55]: counts
Out[55]: 
usefulness-useful            3
problematic-misperception    2
usefulness-not_useful        1
problematic-misspelling      1

In [56]: counts['usefulness-useful']
Out[56]: 3
```

and since bad = total - good, we have

```
In [57]: counts.sum() - counts['usefulness-useful']
Out[57]: 4
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you so much. The first method works perfectly fine. But in the second method, I think there should be a check condition like 
`if exists counts['usefulness-useful']`
otherwise, it is showing errors in the calculations. Also could you tell me how this can be written as a single row in a csv file as output. Eg: Cluster, user, bad, good

Comment: @user1992696: ah, good catch.  You can use `counts.get('usefulness-useful', 0)` instead -- that does the same thing, but if there's no value associated with the key `'usefulness-useful'` it gives 0.